# How do I determine which GraphicsDevice represents the user's default monitor?

Tags: java

I am collecting the screen devices of a multi-monitor environment in Java and would like to know which of these screen devices is the default screen device.

The code `device.getIDString()` returns "\Display0" and so forth for each monitor, so I could simply say something along the lines of `.contains("0")`, but not only is this inelegant, but also I suspect that the format will be different across different vendors or operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc recommends this:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getDefaultScreenDevice()

Comment: Thank you. This works. I guess I missed that when reading the documentation, as I figured relevant methods would be in GraphicsDevice. I will accept this answer as soon as it allows me to do soon.